# Function is continuous

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If function is continuous at $0$ then we have to find the value of $k$

[image]

I got a solution, but I am not able to understand what they have done in second step.

[image]

Can anyone explain me

Comment: Its cosC -cosD formulaformula I think

Comment: Also as x→0 sin x→0,since it is continuous function u can use limit separately to two sin  term which are in product and put sin x→0 instead of x→0 to eliminate the sin function @user123733

Comment: http://www.mathisfunforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3290 @ user123733 check this blog you will find formula for  cosC-cosD

Comment: But I won't understand how second step became third step where is that sin() function?

Comment: $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$

Comment: I want to know more about problem

Comment: @smcc we know what is tanx ,but can u explain how second step changes into third.where is sin()function is gone?

Comment: Because $\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2}$ and $\frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2}$ go to $0$ when $x$ goes to $0$, and $sin(x)$ is equivalent to $x$ near 0. By composition and product, $\frac{sin(\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2})sin(\frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2})}{x^4}$ is equivalent to $\frac{\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2} \frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2}}{x^4} = \frac{(sin(x) + tan(x))(sin(x) - tan(x))}{4x^4}$

Comment: $\tan x-\sin x=\tan x\left(1-\frac{\sin x}{\tan x}\right)=\tan x(1-\cos x)$ because $\frac{\sin x}{\tan x}=\cos x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental fact is that, intuitively, $sin(X) \approx X$ when $X$ is small. Here you replace $X$ with $\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2}$ and $\frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2}$ and that's how you get rid of the outter $sin$.

Formally, you can say that $sin(x) \sim_{0} x$ meaning that $sin(x) = \epsilon(x) x$ or equivalently $x = \epsilon'(x)sin(x)$ where $\epsilon(x)$ (resp. $\epsilon'(x)$) goes to $1$ when $x \to 0$ (in French we call it "equivalent functions" but it seems that the term is different in English, and I wasn't able to find a translation).

Then, both $\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2}$ and $\frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2}$ go to $0$ when $x \to 0$, and in this case you can write $sin(\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2}) \sim_0 \frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2}$ and similarly $sin(\frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2}) \sim_0 \frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2}$. Since you can multiply equivalences, and trivially $\frac{1}{x^4} \sim_0 \frac{1}{x^4}$, you finally get 
$$\frac{sin(\frac{sin(x) + tan(x)}{2})sin(\frac{sin(x) - tan(x)}{2})}{x^4} \sim_0 \frac{(sin(x) + tan(x))(sin(x) - tan(x))}{4x^4}$$

Finally, if two functions are equivalent at some point, and one has a limit $l$, then the other will converge too and must have the same limit. This justifies that you can continue to compute the limit directly on the right hand side of the equivalence, as done in the solution. Even if you haven't seen these notions, you can prove all my claims straightforwardly from the above definition of equivalent functions. You could also have used a Talyor expansion, but although more powerful in general, I find it more complicated for simple cases like that.

Answer (score 1):

> [image]
>
> For small angles($ \theta$ $\rightarrow$ $ 0$),
>   we can say $sin \theta=\theta$..(i)

For $ \theta$,
 $\rightarrow$ $ 0$,

$sin\theta \rightarrow0$

$tan\theta \rightarrow0$

$sin\theta + tan\theta \rightarrow0$

Using ..(i),

$sin\frac{(sin\theta + tan\theta)}{2}=\frac{(sin\theta + tan\theta)}{2}$

[image]